# How to create an xml feed with last post title and content in Wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog setup inside of my Rails application, i need to display a title and a part of content of a last WP post on my Rails home page. I guess i need to create an xml feed which will output my last post and i will parse that with rails everytime the homepage is called...Do you have any idea of how to set this up? Any wordpress plugin for easy generator maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the standard wordpress xml feed available from `your_blog.com/feed`.  If you want to set it to only show the last past the options are in `your_blog.com/wp-admin/options-reading.php`

Then you could either parse the xml manually, or use something like nokogiri to do it for you - http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html